# How can I reach a service from another namespace in Openshift Online?

Tags: openshift

I need to reach a RabbitMQ service from another namespace in Openshift Online.

When I use the following command:

```
oc adm pod-network join-projects --to=<project1> <project2> <project3>
```

I get this error:

```
failed to fetch current network plugin info
```

Is there a way to reach a service from another namespace in Openshift Online?

Note: The purpose here is not joining projects. It is just a way we can choose. The purpose is to reach a service from another namespace.

Comment: OpenShift Online is a multi tenant environment. As such you're not able to join any projects. Assuming you're a Pro customer, you may be able to ask Red Hat support if this can be done for you.

Comment: I will think about your suggestion but it would be time wasting if I need to Red Hat support for every join command.

Comment: Originally creating pod networks between projects required cluster admin access. There was a new network SDN type being developed which would allow a project admin of the two projects involved, to join them. I am not sure of the state of that new network SDN to support the complete multitenancy requirements of Online. Eventually it would, but may still not, I don't know. Either way I would assume Online is still using original SDN network type which doesn't have that ability and so only cluster admin can do it.

Comment: So only way to communicate between projects is have a public HTTP(S) route. So effectively going out to router to come back in. This is of no use if non HTTP traffic. You would also need to have some security on it using a shared access token or something at application level to control access.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Graham.
I simply set up RabbitMQ on the same instance now. I will wait for the feature of project admin, you mentioned.
  Because on Spring, it is adding an extra "port" information after HTTPS route because of this configuration (even if we do not set the port in configuration file of Spring.):

spring.rabbitmq.host=172.30.217.162
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672

Comment: How many projects would you need to join? Pro limits you to 10 projects. Is there a reason for why you wouldn't just deploy RabbitMQ in each of your projects...or deploy all of your related applications that depend on RabbitMQ in the same project?

Comment: I have simple done that right now Will.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error ('failed to fetch current network plugin info') can appear when you are not logged into the oc console. 
Try to login in terminal before joining the POD networks, like:

```
oc login https://console.openshift.test --token=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

or just without token with use of the user with password.